# Ubuntu 16.04.1 WiFi works only after several reboots

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04

Here is a link to the information from the Wireless Info Script: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23433977/

The system is up to date.

My laptop's wifi will show the list of available connections and even show that it is connected without issue but I won't be able to use the internet or even ping my router. Restarting network manager doesn't seem to do anything.

So far the only thing I can do to get it to work is reboot 3-5 times until it randomly decides to work. If I reboot after it starts working I will have to reboot several times again before it starts working again.

Can this be fixed? How?

EDIT: Forgot to mention that it also stops working if I suspend.

Comment: If you suspend and resume does WiFi reconnect ok?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can change the router encryption, change it to WPA2-PSK or WPA2-AES only, no WPA, WEP, or TKIP.

Then disable UFW as it is blocking mDNS traffic.

Reboot and see if the issues are gone, if not then we can disable the power management with

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

Then reboot again and see if it is fixed

Comment: Power management nailed it. I changed the router's encryption and disabled the firewall and it didn't work, then I turned the firewall back on and set the powersave to 2 like you showed me, now i can ping and browse the web to my hearts content after every reboot, suspension, and hibernation. Thank you very much.