# No wifi in ubuntu 16.04 after suspended. A reboot is required to get things working

Tags: networking, 16.04, wireless, suspend, iwlwifi

lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 [8086:0888] (rev c4)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 BGN [8086:4262]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

 sudo lshw -class network

  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 2230
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: c4
       serial: 68:17:29:49:a9:8a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.9.4-040904-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=192.168.43.42 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:30 memory:f2500000-f2501fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: enp5s0
       version: 07
       serial: 28:d2:44:15:f7:93
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:26 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f1404000-f1404fff memory:f1400000-f1403fff
```

I have already tried solutions from below thread but they are not working for me.

[Wifi doesn't work after suspend after 16.04 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761180/wifi-doesnt-work-after-suspend-after-16-04-upgrade)

[16.04 LTS wifi connection issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762198/16-04-lts-wifi-connection-issues)

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2004690

Please, advice.
Thanks.

Comment: Does power management show on in `iwconfig` results before or after suspend?

Comment: Before Suspend
 sudo iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp5s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp4s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"TORVALDS"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 20:E5:2A:E4:29:98   
          Bit Rate=28.9 Mb/s   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-39 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:2  Invalid misc:394   Missed beacon:0

Comment: @Jeremy31
After Suspend
<pre><code>
sudo iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp5s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp4s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
</code></pre>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 16.04.1 WiFi works only after several reboots](http://askubuntu.com/questions/846331/ubuntu-16-04-1-wifi-works-only-after-several-reboots)  See my answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

In my case with a lenovo E540 whenever a usb port was used on wakeup the wifi would not work but when no USB was plugged in the wifi was waking up fine

You might want to try unplugging usb ports on wakeup and plug them in a few seconds

I realize this is just a workaround or it can be used to find the source of the problem.

Comment: didn't work  on my system.