# Wi-Fi does not work after rebooting "device not ready"

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, network-manager, hp

I have a HP laptop and Ubuntu 16.04 installed it alongside Windows 10. After rebooting Ubuntu wi-fi stops working. I get a message "device not ready". But if before starting Ubuntu I first run Windows, reboot it, and run Ubuntu, wi-fi works again. Or if I shut down the PC and start again, it works again, but not if I only reboot.

```
$ sudo lshw -c network
*-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
   vendor: Ralink corp.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
   logical name: wlo1
   version: 00
   serial: 70:18:8b:5e:7d:bb
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet 
physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=4.10.0-
38-generic firmware=0.37 ip=192.168.0.103 latency=0 link=yes 
multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:16 memory:c3510000-c351ffff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
   logical name: eno1
   version: 07
   serial: a0:48:1c:11:5d:4d
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:27 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c3404000-c3404fff memory:c3400000-c3403fff memory:c3410000-c341ffff
```

---

```
$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Is your Windows completely shut down when this error occurs on Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, I can't run both OS at the same time

Comment: Obviously Windows is doing something as it only works after using windows, I suspect Windows might be in what is called a `fast boot` state. Is this a fresh install of Ubuntu? See if you can disable `fast boot` on Windows!

Comment: Yes, it is fresh, ubuntu and windows are on the different partitions of the disk

Comment: Is fast boot enabled on Windows, if so please disable it!

Comment: This issue appear even I don't run window before running ubuntu, but strange thing, if I shut down pc, turn on, run ubuntu ->  wi-fi works. I do a reboot and again  ->  wi-fi not working

Comment: Is Windows `fast boot` disabled?

Comment: yes, I even haven't this option in "Power Options" it seems like my laptop don't support this function

Comment: see this https://askubuntu.com/questions/791945/wifi-not-connecting-after-restart-in-ubuntu-16-04 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/761180/wifi-doesnt-work-after-suspend-after-16-04-upgrade?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 16.04.1 WiFi works only after several reboots](https://askubuntu.com/questions/846331/ubuntu-16-04-1-wifi-works-only-after-several-reboots)

Comment: Nope it is not a duplicate, I tried everything from these topics

Comment: Oh, man, I believe I have read long time ago something *(blog post? bugtracker?)* about exactly that issue, but can't find it again :/ IIRC the problem was that upon reboot some hw register not gets dropped to a default value which the driver expects, thus leading to problems. Try upgrading to the latest kernel and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks man! It really helped me) I had 4.10 version, updated to 4.14 and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Per comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976027/do-not-work-wi-fi-after-rebooting-device-not-ready#comment1566581_976027) upgrading to the latest kernel *(4.14 as of writing the words)* helped.

I believe I've read somewhere about this problem *(blog post or bugtracker)*, but can't find the source. IIRC the problem was that some hardware register ought to be dropped upon reboot to a certain value, but actually doesn't, which led to problems.